# How to make my code dont repeat activity after random?

Tags: android

I just did to random activity, my question is how can I prevent the already opened activity to open again. example, I pick from 1-5, I pick 3, I shouldn't have to pick again 3 because I already pick it, just choose only to the remaining number.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onBackPressed() {
}

public void openNewActivity(View view) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int x = rnd.nextInt(3) + 1;
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    switch (x) {
        case 1:
            intent.setClass(this, Question1.class);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent.setClass(this, Question2.class);
            break;
        case 3:
            intent.setClass(this, Answer1.class);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you put your Activity classes into an array like this:

```
private ArrayList<Class<? extends Activity>> activitiesNotOpened;
```

In `onCreate`:

```
activitiesNotOpened = new ArrayList<>();
activitiesNotOpened.add(Question1.class);
activitiesNotOpened.add(Question2.class);
activitiesNotOpened.add(Answer1.class);
```

Now you can just do this in `openNewActivity`:

```
if (activitiesNotOpened.size() > 0) {
    Random rnd = new Random(); // Note: I suggest you to put this line at class level
    int x = rnd.nextInt(activitiesNotOpened.size());
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, activitiesNotOpened.get(x));
    activitiesNotOpened.remove(x);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

How does this work?

The reason why this works is that we select a random activity from the array list. Then we remove the activity that is opened from the array list, each time we open a new activity. This way, the same activity will not be selected again.

Comment: @mikazuki If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

First Create a list and add 1 to 3 numbers in it,

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();


    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        list.add(i); // add 1 to 3 in list
    }
```

Then Change your method like this ,

```
public void openNewActivity(View view) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = rnd.nextInt(Collections.max(list)) + 1; //Collections.max(list) returns maximum value availble in the list
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                intent.setClass(this, Question1.class);
                break;
            case 2:
                intent.setClass(this, Question2.class);
                break;
            case 3:
                intent.setClass(this, Answer1.class);
                break;
        }
        list.remove(list.indexOf((x-1))); //remove that number from list
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply sir ^_^